# Windows Safari Freezes When Silverlight Calls a JavaScript window.alert/prompt

Tags: javascript, silverlight, safari, alert, freeze

I have a Siverlight application, which needs to get something from the web page that hosts it.  So I'm using `HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("JS_OpenProject")` in Silverlight.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function JS_OpenProject() {
    // window.alert also crashes
    window.alert("Here is a window.alert");

    // window.prompt also crashes
    //var result = window.prompt("Please input the id of the project to be opened:", "12345");

    return result;
}
```

Safari freezes every time when the JavaScript method `JS_OpenProject` is called.  If I remove the `window.alert` and `window.prompt`, it's fine.

On Windows, I tested my Silverlight application with JavaScript calling against IE, Chrome and Firefox, everything works fine, but just the Safari.

I have googled a lot, but no luck.

Please advise!

Thanks.

Peter

Comment: Do you absolutely have to worry about supporting Safari on Windows ? It's only at around 5% of browser usage, and almost all of that would be Mac folks, surely.

Comment: At least it's one of the 4 main browsers in Windows :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with FireFox and that seems to have been corrected now. The problem arises when Silverlight is run in windowsless mode.

If you don't need it turn it off, it will run even faster.

Comment: In my case, it only happens on Safari, other browsers are okay.